# iOS11 - "Turn on Bluetooth" prompt not working

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios11, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am using bluetooth in my app to work with iBeacons (Location Services)

Since iOS11, [and the new functionality brought in Control Center](https://www.zdnet.com/article/ios-11s-control-center-may-say-bluetooth-wi-fi-are-off-but-thats-just-not-true/), my bluetooth **prompts don't show** when turning bluetooth **off** via `Control Center`.

But when I turn bluetooth **off** in the `Settings App`, **the prompt does appear**.

I'm setting `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` to be `YES`.

Here is the code where I'm initialising the `CBCentralManager`:

```
_bluetoothManager =[[CBCentralManager alloc]
                    initWithDelegate:self
                    queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                    options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @(YES)}];
```

When getting the bluetooth state from `centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central`, I'm getting the same **OFF** state when turning bluetooth off from both the `Settings App` and `Control Center.` But the prompt only appears when turning off via `Settings`.

How can I get the "Turn on Bluetooth" prompt to work when turning Bluetooth off via Control Center?

The only workaround that I can think of is to set `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` to be `NO` and then create a custom dialog to open the `Settings App`. It's not possible to open direct to the bluetooth settings page on iOS 11.

Comment: did you find anything on this?

Comment: For the record I saw in other SO answers that this was a bug in some versions of iOS11.